# cv::Mat initialization using array

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, mat

I experienced a strange behavior after for example initializing through

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat h = cv::Mat(2, 2, CV_32F, {1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0});
    std::cout << h << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

cout prints out [1, 1; 1, 1]. WTF just happened? I'm using eclipse on ubuntu, gcc version 5.4, OpenCV 3.2

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using a valid `Mat` constructor. You have a few options:

1. From an array:

   ```
   float pf[] = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f };
   Mat1f m1(2, 2, pf);
   ```

   or

   ```
   std::vector<float> vf = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f };
   Mat1f m2(2, 2, vf.data());
   ```
2. With comma initializers:

   ```
   Mat1f m3 = (Mat1f(2, 2) << 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f);
   ```
3. If the matrix is small, you can use `Matx`:

   ```
   Matx22f m4(1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f);
   ```

---

Note that a `Mat1f` is a typedef for `Mat_<float>`, which is a `Mat` of type `CV_32FC1`.

---

Using your method doesn't work because `{1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0}` constructs  `cv::Scalar`, so you call the constructor `Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, cv::Scalar)`. Since you have only 1 channel, the matrix is initialized with the first value of this scalar, which is the first value in your initializer list.

Note that this is just a coincidence since your matrix has 4 elements (the maximum number supported by `Scalar`s). If you use a higher number of elements:

```
cv::Mat h(2, 3, CV_32F, {3.f, 2.f, 1.f, 0.f, 2.f, 5.f});
```

the code should not compile.

Comment: What differs my method from your first initialization using an array?

Comment: Added explanation @YuZ