# c++ opencv Mat Value

Tags: c++

```
cv::Mat K(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);

K.at<double>(0, 0) = 407.87327205;
K.at<double>(0, 1) = 0.0;
K.at<double>(0, 2) = 297.88672999;

K.at<double>(1, 0) = 0.0;
K.at<double>(1, 1) = 408.85701444;
K.at<double>(1, 2) = 217.4312281;

K.at<double>(2, 0) = 0.0;
K.at<double>(2, 1) = 0.0;
K.at<double>(2, 2) = 1.0;
```

C++ Opencv Mat =>
Can the source code last a bit shorter?
Sorry for the poor English.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44966334/12041020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use [comma initialization](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#details):

```cpp
cv::Mat K = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
  407.87327205,   0.0       , 297.88672999,
    0.0       , 408.85701444, 217.4312281 ,
    0.0       ,   0.0       ,   1.0
);
```

This (ab)uses the little-used [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in the C++ language. The outer parentheses are necessary for it to work!